# Riesz Decomposition theorem and scalar product

Tags: vector-spaces, bilinear-form

I want to solve this problem.

$V$ a given vector space of finite dimension, with a bilinear form as a scalar product, which is positive definite ( $ \forall u \in V, \langle u,u\rangle \geq 0 $ ).
I have to show that :

> $$ \exists d \,\in \mathbb N^*, \ F : V \rightarrow \mathbb R^d \, \
>  \text{such  that} \\ \forall u,v \in V : \ \langle u, v\rangle \ = \ F(u) \cdot F(v)
> $$ where $ \cdot $ is the classical scalar product (standard).

---

I tried to find something for the case where $ V = \mathbb R ^2 $ but in vain... 
I think that $F$ has to be a square matrix of the same dimension as $V$. But how to show this? I know how to prove the Riesz decumposition on scalar product and it seems almost like the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{f_1, \ldots, f_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$ with respect to $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ and let $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ be the canonical basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Define a linear map $F : V \to \mathbb{R}^n$ as $Fx = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle x, f_i\rangle e_i$.

Let $u,v \in V$ we have

\begin{align}
\langle u, v\rangle &= \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n\langle u, f_i\rangle f_i, \sum_{j=1}^n\langle v, f_j\rangle f_j\right\rangle \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \langle u, f_i\rangle \langle v, f_j\rangle \overbrace{\langle f_i, f_j\rangle}^{=\delta_{ij}} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\langle u,f_i\rangle \langle v, f_i\rangle \\
&= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \langle u,f_i\rangle e_i\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\langle v,f_i\rangle e_i \right)\\
&= Fu \cdot Fv
\end{align}

so $F$ is the desired map.

Comment: omg it seems so simple :( and I struggled so much. Thank you @mechanodroid